# How do I set a Base SDK of 3.1 in XCode 3.2.3?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode3.2

I upgraded to XCode 3.2.3 recently, and now, I see i can't set a base SDK to a previous version. How do I build to allow my app to run on 3.1.3 now?

I am in a serious bind, because I committed to delivering to 3.1.3.  :-(

I tried going to look for the 3.1 SDK on the Apple Developer Program site, but all i see is iOS 4.0 and iOS SDK Beta.

Any thanks would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Open the Project Settings (Make sure "All Configurations" is set)
- Project -> Edit Project Settings

2) Find "Base SDK", it is found in the "Architectures" category and set it to "iPhone Device 4.0".

3) Find "iPhone OS Deployment Target", it is found in the "Deployment" category and set it to "iPhone OS 3.1.3".

- Ensure the same settings for your target
- Project -> "Edit Active Target" (then follow the same steps)

Answer (score 1):

The Base SDK has no bearing on which version of the SDK the app can run on, just which one it is being built on.  Set the Base SDK to 4.0, and the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to 3.1.3 and you should be good.